# How to copy an image from a table in one document to another using Python Docx

Tags: python-3.x, python-docx

I am trying to copy an existing document which includes tables and create another document.
The text from the tables is copied perfectly but the images within tables are not being copied.

I tried using deepcopy. The code is as follows:

```py
def func_main():
    global new_tbl
    tableImg = document.tables[0]
    tbl = tableImg._tbl
    new_tbl = copy.deepcopy(tbl)
    edit_func()

def edit_func():
    document = Document(fileName + ".docx")
    paragraph = document.add_paragraph()
    paragraph._p.addnext(new_tbl)
    document.save(fileName+".docx")
```

The image is not displayed in the new document.

[image: Image after copy]

How to copy an image from the table to a new document and having the image being displayed?

Answer (score 0):

you can remove the origin image then loop for the new table instance and use  `add_picture` method,it works for me.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)
For example you can add a code snippet.